# Underlining not working in matplotlib graphs for the following code using tex

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tex

Underlining not working in matplotlib graphs for the following code

```
    mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
    collector.__ax.set_xticklabels([r'$\underline{%s}$' % x for x in plt.xticks()[0]])
    plt.show()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: 
\underline{260.0}
^
Unknown symbol: \underline (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

Is there any way to avoid this error, do I need to import any package.

Comment: I *should* work. Maybe if you show a [mcve] and its full traceback it can hint at some problem you have on your computer

Comment: Since I have the same issue : The following fails :  `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.5,0.5,r"$\underline{This fails}$")` with `ValueError: 
\underline{This fails}
^
Unknown symbol: \underline, found '\'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)` while the following doesn't : `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.5,0.5,r"$\frac{This doesn't}{fail}$")`.